# Italics not working under Blockquote tab

Tags: wordpress

Working in Wordpress. The default style sheet had:

blockquote {font-style:italic}

and all text including h3/h4 appeared italicised. I removed the font-style:italic. Now even if I put italics-formatting-code in text, italics don't appear. When I had not removed the styling, "italics-formatting-code" cancelled the styling (opposite of italics, is roman). this means that the font is available in italics.

Any ideas? Thanks

(Sorry, I tried many times putting the italics-coding, but it kept disappearing)

Answer (score 0):

I will just use a DIV and move on.